# $H \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group, let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$, with $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that $H \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$.

So I need to show that if an element is in $H$ and $K$ then the conjugate is in $H \cap K$. So let $a \in H \cap K$ then $a\in H$ and $a\in K$. Also, let $x\in K$. Thus $xax^{-1} \in K$ since $x,a \in K$. $xax^{-1}\in H$ because $H$ is normal in $G$. Therefore $xax^{-1} \in H\cap K$ and is a normal subgroup.

Is this the correct path to prove this or am I completely lost?

Comment: And your question is… ?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_with_Normal_Subgroup_is_Normal

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof starts off fine. You showed that $xax^{-1}\in H$ correctly.
But it goes astray at the last sentence.

You say "Therefore $xax^{-1}\in K$" but you haven't given a reason for your "Therefore". Of course it is obvious, so you could say "Obviously $xax^{-1}\in K$" and to be safe, if you are being graded, add "because both $x$ and $a$ are in $K$".

At the end of that sentence you say "and $K$ is a normal subgroup." This is a misstatement, you haven't proved it, and it may not be true. What you need to say is something like: "Thus $H\cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$."

Comment: Being a slow writer, I, like Jose, was responding to an earlier version of the question. Also, I did not see Jose's answer before posting mine.